# Windows API: handling keypress event of external window application through C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I have one external application window opened. Through my winform application, i want to execute certain code when keypress event happens on this external window.

I know window handle of this external application window.

Any help will be truely appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to set up a hook on the external application window with
[SetWindowHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then monitor the [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

I am actually not sure that it will work in C# because the hook callback has to be in a native DLL. You might have to write a portion of the solution in an unmanaged language.

Alternatively, you could use a [global keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c), possibly combined with a check of the currently active window.