# Handling Single Key Presses, Multiple Times

Tags: vb.net, keypress

Before someone says that this has been asked before, I spent a good 2 hours today trying different wordings in Google to hopefully find an answer, and nothing was what I was looking for. A majority of what I found dealt with using key combinations like "CTRL + A" and that is not what I am trying to go for here.

I was tasked with creating an application that looks, and plays the piano. Thus far, I have set it up to where when you click the button (a piano key), it plays that particular frequency (using the `Beep` function from the "Kernel32" library?)

Now, what I want to be able to do is to press keys like A, D, and G, and the same time to play a chord, which would translate out to the notes C, E, and G.

What I tried doing was putting everything under a `KeyPress` sub.

```
Sub frmForm1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If Keys.A Then
            C_KeyPress()
        End If

        If Keys.S Then
            D_KeyPress()
        End If
    End Sub
```

But when I press the A (or the S key in this case), it executes both `If` statements even though I only pressed the A key. I have no clue how to make it so that it only plays the particular note that I have assigned that key to.

(I'm not sure whether this needs to go into another question or not but, how would I go about handling 3 <= keys at one time, so one could create a chord?)

Comment: It has been asked (ha ha). Here you are:

[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251852/windows-api-handling-keypress-event-of-external-window-application-through-c-sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing the `Keys.<something>` value instead of comparing it to the actual key press data. `KeyPress` only gives the character pressed, but you could do some logic with it. For example:

```
If Char.ToLower(e.KeyChar) = Char.ToLower(ChrW(Keys.A)) Then
    C_KeyPress()
End If
```

Comment: When I use that snippet, it will now only work if you are pressing shift to get the uppercase A. How do I allow it to work without pressing shift?

Comment: Pass them both through String.UCase() when comparing

Comment: @DanVerdolino Thanks, added that (but used `Char.ToLower` instead)-

Answer (score 0):

you could

1. flag all keys as up
2. use the key down event to flag each key as 'down' as it goes down
3. use the key up even to reflag each key as 'up' as it goes up
4. have a timer loop that in each tick decides which sound to play based on the keys that are flagged as 'down' at that time