# UWP: listen keyboard event when app is in background

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I'm going to create a UWP app which provides sound effect for the keyboard keyUp/keyDown event.

I wrote code below in `MainPage.xaml.cs`. It worked as expected when my app was in foreground but failed when it's minimized/in background.

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown +=
    (window, e) =>
    {
        MyMediaElement.Source = new Uri(this.BaseUri, currentSoundEffect.EnterKeyAudio;);
    };
```

I know there's in-process/out-of-process background tasks that can be registered in my app. But as per this doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks, background tasks have to be triggered and can only be triggered by `System event triggers`, `Maintenance trigger` and `DeviceUseTrigger`.

My questions are 
1. how could I listen keyboard event when my app is not in foreground?
2. if I have to put the event handler(which plays audio) inside a background task, how could I trigger that task?

Sorry if my questions don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to listen to the windows api, not just the currently open window, which since it is not active, is not receiving keypress events:

[Windows API: handling keypress event of external window application through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251852/windows-api-handling-keypress-event-of-external-window-application-through-c-sh)